# Legend doesn't fit (different resolution)

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design, legend

I have got a form with a fieldset and a legend in it and I would like, the legend's background to fit  the full width of the fieldset. But I don't know how?

Here is my fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/pe72bnk2/1/)

HTML code:

```
<div id="search_job_simple" class="form_padding">
<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Jobsuche eingrentzen:
            <span>Wählen Sie eine "Jobart" und einen "Stadtteil", oder erweitern Sie ihre Suche unter "Mehr Auswahl".</span>
        </legend>
        <label for="j_select">
            <span>Jobart:</span>
            <select name="j_select" size="1">
                <option>Gelegenheitsjob</option>
                <option>Ausbildungsplatz</option>
                <option>Praktika</option>
                <option>Fachkräfte</option>
                <option>Freiemitarbeiter/Freelancer</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="j_destrict">
            <span>Stadtteil:</span>
            <select name="j_destrict" size="1">
                <option>Charlottenburg</option>
                <option>Friedrichshain</option>
                <option>Hellersdorf</option>
                <option>Hohenschönhausen</option>
                <option>Köpenick</option>
                <option>Kreuzberg</option>
                <option>Lichtenberg</option>
                <option>Marzahn</option>
                <option>Mitte</option>
                <option>Neuköln</option>
                <option>Pankow</option>
                <option>Prenzlauer Berg</option>
                <option>Reinickendorf</option>
                <option>Schöneberg</option>
                <option>Spandau</option>
                <option>Steglitz</option>
                <option>Tempelhof</option>
                <option>Tiergarten</option>
                <option>Treptow</option>
                <option>Wedding</option>
                <option>Weißensee</option>
                <option>Wilmersdorf</option>
                <option>Zehlendorf</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" name="suche_f_btn" class="submit_button">Los!</button>
        <span class="more_options">Mehr Auswahl</span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS code:

```
/***********************************************
    Alles auf Null setzen
***********************************************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 100%;
}


/***********************************************
            Header
***********************************************/

#header {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../pics/bg.png);
}

#logo {
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(../pics/jobber_logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:45px 25px;

}


/***********************************************
            Navigation
***********************************************/

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 50px;
}

/* Links in der Navigation */
nav a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5c5c5c;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav a:active {
    color: black;
}


 /***********************************************
            Content
***********************************************/

#content {
    clear: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Jede zweite Zeile in der Tabelle farbig */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

th {
    background-color: #8dc043;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
    font: 18px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

tr {
    /*border: 2px solid #47641c;*/
}

td {
    border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
    padding: 8px;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}

/*sets padding around the table*/
.table_padding {
    margin: 0 45px 45px 45px;
    padding-top: 45px; 
}


/***********************************************
                Footer
***********************************************/

footer {
    background-color: #696969;
    height: 50px;
}

footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 0 50px;
}

/* Links in der Navigation */
footer a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

footer a:visited {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: white;
}

footer a:active {
    color: white;
}


/***********************************************
                Classes
***********************************************/

.more_options {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.less_options {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}


/***********************************************
                ID's
***********************************************/

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
}

 #feedback {
     padding: 20px 20px 20px 45px;
}

#control_center {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#control_center_links {
    padding: 45px;
}



/***********************************************
                Forms
***********************************************/

.form_padding, #form_1, #form_2 {
    margin: 0 45px 0 45px;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

.smart-green {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}

.smart-green fieldset {
    border: none;
}

.smart-green legend {
    font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 25px 15px 15px 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8dc043;
}

.smart-green legend>span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.smart-green label {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 40px 5px;
    clear: left;
}

.smart-green label>span {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}

.smart-green input[type="text"], .smart-green input[type="email"], .smart-green textarea, .smart-  green select {
    color: #555;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
    font: normal 14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.smart-green textarea{
    height:100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.smart-green select {
    background: url('down-arrow.png') no-repeat right, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #E9E9E9 100%);
    background: url('down-arrow.png') no-repeat right, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FBFBFB), color-stop(100%,#E9E9E9));
    appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}

.smart-green .submit_button {
    clear: left;
    background-color: #8dc043;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inherit;
}

.smart-green .submit_button:hover {
    background-color:#80A24A;
}

.sub_field {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub_field legend {
    font: 18px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    width: 96.2%;
    background: yellow;
}

.radio_matches {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
}

.radio_destrict {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.radio_destrict li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

I have got another problem. I would like for this element:

```
<span class="less_options">Weniger Auswahl</span>
```

to be *next* to the button and not under it. But my first question is more important.

Comment: you'd probably be better off splitting the two questions up into two SO questions...

Comment: OK, I going to try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the legend be as wide as its parent, add `width:100%;`. With padding, this will make the legend WIDER than the fieldset - so you'll also need to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to prevent it overflowing.

```
.smart-green legend {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;   
}
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pe72bnk2/5/

More reading on box-sizing: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the "box-sizing" element.. Thanks a lot!! :D